# When is an option ON and when is it OFF?

Tags: system-settings

I am a new Ubuntu user. I was curious to install it. But I have some difficulties to understand the options in the system preferences. It's because  I don't know if an option is on or off (see picture).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This means it is ON.

This one makes it more clear: when 'auto-hide the Launcher' is set to OFF it grays out the selections that would be available if 'auto-hide the Launcher' was set to ON:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I still find it confusing though. Is there a way to have checkboxes? In the real world, sliders work for me. On a desktop it confuses me. I always have to take a little break and think: 'Is this thingy on or off?'. Do I slide it to off or is it off and I will slide it to on? And the other way round, of course. Very confusing concept.